# Azure function with input date parameter to decide when to trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working on Azure function and in this function I am providing the shared mailbox permission to user.

unfortunility `Add-MailboxPermission` doesn't have date param to ensure that permission will be applicable on specified date. So the moment we execute the command user will have access to shared mailbox.

Is there any way to execute azure function with datetime as input param to execute that request on that datetime (future datetime).

Comment: which kind of trigger are you using at this moment? HttpTrigger?

Comment: yes. right now its HTTP trigger

Comment: Could you please provide your function code how you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is another way to do it, but in my work we used two functions.

1. We have the httptrigger function that receive the order, evaluate, calculate the time and queue a message for the specific datetime on which you want to execute the action.
2. Then the second function which is a queuetrigger and is listening for the messages to execute the action.

If you want to enqueue the message for less time than seven days you can use a storage queue, for more time you have to use a service bus.